# How do I make query statement to mongoDB with $and and nested $or from dynamic search string?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have input search string from UI (ex. ‘tree, orange; fresh’) and send string to Node.js to split string with separator before send them to MongoDB. Then I have string array

```
['tree', 'orange' ,’fresh’]
```

How do I make the query $and with nested $or like this below :

```
db.collection('product').find({ $and : [
      { $or : [ { ProductNameTh : 'tree' }, { ProductNameEn : 'tree' } , { ProductNameCn : 'tree' } ] },
      { $or : [ { ProductNameTh : 'orange' }, { ProductNameEn : 'orange' } , { ProductNameCn : 'orange' } ] } ,
      { $or : [ { ProductNameTh : 'fresh' }, { ProductNameEn : 'fresh' } , { ProductNameCn : 'fresh' } ] }           
] } )
```

However, the search string is very dynamic from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/in/) operator. You don't need the [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and) operator here because:

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions.

```js
var arr = ['tree', 'orange' , 'fresh'];
db.product.find( {
    'ProductNameTh': { '$in': arr }, 
    'ProductNameEn': { '$in': arr }, 
    'ProductNameCn': { '$in': arr }
})
```

You can generate your query using a function like this:

```js
function queryGenerator(fields, array) { 
   var query = {}; 
   for (var ix = 0; ix < fields.length; ix++)
       query[fields[ix]] = {'$in': arr};
   return query; 
}
```

Then use can use your function like this:

```js
var fields = [ 'ProductNameTh', 'ProductNameEn', 'ProductNameCn' ];
var arr = ['tree', 'orange' , 'fresh'];
db.product.find(queryGenerator(fields, arr)); // or var q = queryGenerator(fields, arr); and db.product.find(q)
```

**You don't need the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator here.**

Comment: First of all, @user3100115 thanks for editing and answering. Your answer is awesome but almost complete. I have prepared the query statement like these
    <br>
    db.product.find({
        // … get create from Generated query function
    })
    <br>
In Generated query function how do I create the var query object including $or operator. It’s not like string concat.

Comment: @iPatz as I mentioned you don't need the `$or` here. Please check the edited answer.